# fast video playback in debian jessie

Tags: debian, video

Video plays too fast in flash browser plugin and some of the video players but not VLC.

Installation is fresh except that Nvidia driver is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to 4.2 kernel from backports and updated my nvidia drivers to 355 with patch from nvidia forums for compilation with 4.2 dependency.

Problem disappeared.

Also i add additional information on problem here:

glxgears behaves strangely showing exactly 60 FPS like VSYNC beeing enabled but "Sync to VBlank" is still unchecked in nvidia configuration.

Before that glxgears were showing nearly 18000 FPS without explicitly specifying vblank_mode=0:

```
vblank_mode=0 glxgears
```

provides the same nearly 18000 FPS.